# Smarty variable in XSLT: is this possible?

Tags: xslt, smarty

i have variables of a customer in my email service provider database, and based on those variables i want to show the shop of that value:

```
{if $profile.pos1 == '1'}
<xsl:for-each select="//shop[@id='1']">
show content of shop 1
</xsl:for-each>
{/if}

{if $profile.pos1 == '17'}
<xsl:for-each select="//shop[@id='17']">
show content of shop 17
</xsl:for-each>
{/if}

{if $profile.pos1 == '18'}
<xsl:for-each select="//shop[@id='18']">
show content of shop 18
</xsl:for-each>
{/if}
```

etc etc.

But this is hardcoded, so obviously not scalable. How can I solve this?
XSLT is parsed first, then smarty (!).

Smarty 3.1.14

Thanks

Comment: Is `<xsl:for-each select="//shop">` not an option, just dropping the identifier? Or if you want only some to be used, have a variable contain those which you want to display, separated by spaces, and then use `contains` to check if the id is in the variable list.

Comment: i really want the variable (profile.pos1) to decide which "shop id" it chooses to show.

Comment: I don't know smarty at all, but could you try doing `<xsl:for-each select="//shop[@id='{$profile.pos1}']">`